# Trouble cloning a live Wordpress site to a new site on a local server?

Tags: plugins, updates, duplicates

I'm new to Wordpress and need to set up a local testing environment where I can make changes to a CLONE of the live site. It is using version 3.4.2., hosted on Dreamhost,  and contains several outdated plugins.

-I used Dreamhost's 'Backup Your Account' tool and downloaded 4 files that include the current contents of all FTP users, mailboxes, and MySQL databases.
-I installed Wordpress with MAMP and created a folder 'testsite'.
-I copied all 4 files into the folder, as well as the WP installation folder.
-I set MAMP's document root to : MAMP > htdocs > testsite
-I set up a new database and now have a new WP site running locally (version 4.6.1.)

MAMP's root connection to the testsite folder I created is the only connection I know exists between the backups and my new site. And while the local installation was successful, I am unsure how to transfer those copied files to the new site, as a duplicate.

Other approaches tried:

Plugin 1. I found this tutorial to use the Duplicator plugin with WP, https://www.w3newbie.com/how-to-use-the-duplicator-wordpress-plugin-with-mamp/ , but the original site's version is incompatible with plugin. Of course this may be fixed with a site upgrade, but then I risk breaking the live site. Is there a way I can use Duplicator on my new site instead?

Plugin 2. I installed & activated WP Clone on both sites. I saved a backup on the original site with this plugin, copied the URL I was given, and pasted it into the New site to 'Restore from URL'. When I hit the restore button, it never loads all the way - I refresh and it does not work.

Using the clone I was able to download a zip file of the content, which I imported on the new site using WordPress importer. The categories, posts and pages are there, but the theme, media and other content is missing.

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Exactly what are the files you were sent? And where have you placed them within your testsite WP installation?

Comment: You will only need two things from your live site. The database, there should only be one, this contains all your content and settings. And the wp-content folder, this contains all your images, plugins and themes.

Comment: I updated the post with more info. ^^ Also, I tried deleting everything but the WP installation folder, mySQL file database file and  wp content, but it stopped my local server from running.